# Torch.cuda.is_available() keeps switching to False

Tags: pytorch

I have tried several solutions which hinted at what to do when the CUDA GPU is available and CUDA is installed but the `Torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False`. They did help but only temporarily, meaning `torch.cuda-is_available()` reported True but after some time, it switched back to False. I use CUDA 9.0.176 and GTX 1080. What should I do to get the permanent effect?

I tried the following methods:

https://forums.fast.ai/t/torch-cuda-is-available-returns-false/16721/5
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15612

Note: When `torch.cuda.is_available()` works fine but then at some point switches to `False`, then I have to restart the computer and then it works again (for some time).

Comment: I am facing the same problem, but inside docker. It's so annoying that I need to restart the docker from time to time. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 19):

The reason for `torch.cuda.is_available()` resulting `False` is the incompatibility between the versions of `pytorch` and `cudatoolkit`.

As on Jun-2022, the current version of pytorch is compatible with **cudatoolkit=11.3** whereas the current **cuda toolkit version = 11.7**. [Source](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

Solution:

0. Uninstall Pytorch for a fresh installation. You cannot install an old version on top of a new version without force installation (using `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package_name>`.
1. Run `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch` to install pytorch.
2. Install CUDA 11.3 version from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.3.0-download-archive.

You are good to go.
[image: torch.cuda.is_available() --> True]

Comment: +1 This solved my problem. I tried it using CUDA 11.6 and it works perfectly. (in this case, the cuda-11.6.0-download-archive should be used together with `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`)

Comment: I tried nvcc (kudatoolkit) 12.2, 11.3, and 11.6, the torch.cuda.is_available() always give me "False". I have one NIVIDIA GPU on graphic card by "lshw" command.

Comment: The current `pytorch` with version `2.0.1` is compatible with `CUDA 11.7` and `CUDA 11.8` . See https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
Try with those versions of CUDA.
The command is `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia` for installing with Anaconda on Windows with `CUDA 11.8`.
Then you need to download `CUDA 11.8` from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive and install it.

Answer (score 6):

Also with `torch.cuda.is_available ()` had false. 
But when installing the **Nvidia** driver to the most updated version **436.48**, True is displayed. I previously updated **Pytorch to 1.2.0**.
I have windows 10 and **Anaconda**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Install CUDA 9.1 using apt-get, following the instructions in this link:

https://cryptoandcoffee.com/mining-gems/cuda-9-0-install-ubuntu-16-04-apt-get/

2. Installed PyTorch using pip:

   ```
   pip install torchvision ( this will install both torch and torchvision )
   ```
3. Rebooted

Now try it:

```
~$ python -c 'import torch; print torch.cuda.is_available()'
```

Answer (score 2):

I saw this issue as well. The reason was the CUDA version used by Pytorch being out of sync with the installed Nvidia driver. As in Joe's answer, the solution was updating the Nvidia drivers. Some other important background info to be aware of:

- Each release of CUDA requires a minimum Nvidia driver version (see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver) for a compatibility table).
- You can check your Nvidia driver version with `nvidia-smi`.
- **Pytorch comes pre-packaged with a version of CUDA that may be different from the version you installed on your computer.**
- The CUDA version that you installed manually is the one shows up when you run `nvidia-smi`. Even if your driver version is compatible with this CUDA version, it may be incompatible with the Pytorch CUDA version.
- You can get the Pytorch CUDA version by printing the `torch.version.cuda` variable in ipython or in a Python program. This is the version that determines the needed Nvidia driver version.

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'torch.cuda' has no attribute 'version'`

Comment: thanks - should be `torch.version.cuda`. I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to re-install pytorch using pip instead of conda fore example

```
pip install torch==1.8.1+cu101 torchvision==0.9.1+cu101 torchaudio==0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Instead of

```
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

(Don't mind the above Torch version difference; it is just for illustration.)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of the notebook that has been chosen is incompatible with pytorch and cuda. For example, the default kernel for Vertex AI notebooks is
`XGBoost 1.7`. You will need to change it to `Pytorch x.yy`.

The pytorch kernel version you select should be compatible with the underlying CUDA GPU driver version installed. You can check the driver version with `nvidia-smi` on the terminal.

Also check the pytorch version that is compatible with the driver version here. https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

For ex. if you need pytorch to work with cuda version 11.6, then you need to install with `pip install torch==1.13.1+cu116 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116`