# I have a GPU and CUDA installed in Windows 10 but Pytorch's torch.cuda.is_available() returns false; how can I correct this?

Tags: windows, pytorch

I have PyTorch installed on a Windows 10 machine with a Nvidia GTX 1050 GPU. I have installed the CUDA Toolkit and tested it using [Nvidia instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html) and that has gone smoothly, including execution of the suggested tests.

However, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False`. How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you install pytorch ? It looks like you have installed cpu version .

Comment: Check this: https://pytorch.org/

Comment: Try `a=torch.cuda.FloatTensor()` and check the error. Also, check the your environment information using [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pytorch/pytorch/master/torch/utils/collect_env.py).

Comment: Thank you, you were both helpful, it works now!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I also had the same issue.
And running this => `a=torch.cuda.FloatTensor()`, gave the assertion error `AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled` . ...which kind of cleared that i was running pytorch without cuda.

Steps:

1. Make sure you have un-installed Pytorch by invoking the following command:

   `pip uninstall torch`
2. Go to https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ and select your system configurations(as shown in the figure).
3. Copy the exact command from the `Run this command` dialog and run it on your terminal.

[image]

Comment: Legend- the uninstall is key

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue, and it turned out that I installed a CPU-only version by running the command provided by
https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/.

If you have CUDA 10.2 installed like me, the website would likely give you `pip install torch===1.7.1 torchvision===0.8.2 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`, which **doesn't explicitly specify CPU or GPU.**

[image: wrong command to install]

In my case, it routed me to `cpu/torch-1.7.1%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`, which is a CPU version, instead of `cu102/torch-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` for my CUDA 10.2.

My workaround is that, directly go to `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` and download the binary file matching your environment, and simply install from downloads folder:

`pip install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall torch===1.7.1 torchvision===0.8.2 -f .\Downloads\`

Comment: This is the one thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

The reason for `torch.cuda.is_available()` resulting `False` is the incompatibility between the versions of `pytorch` and `cudatoolkit`.

As on Jun-2022, the current version of pytorch is compatible with **cudatoolkit=11.3** whereas the current **cuda toolkit version = 11.7**. [Source](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

Solution:

1. Run `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch` to install pytorch.
2. Install CUDA 11.3 version from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.3.0-download-archive.

You are good to go.
[image: torch.cuda.is_available() --> True]

The original answer is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72650265/10468354. This is just for quick reference:

Comment: I just had to go to https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and install the latest in Feb 2023

Answer (score 0):

I just spent about an hour fighting this problem, breaking down and building up at least four different conda environments. I finally got something to work using the same [matrix selector at their web site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) but selected `conda`, because conda seems to be working hard on getting a conda installation to work. And it worked!  Here is the command that worked in my conda command line:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Obviously these details may change, but the command generated worked! Such a great feeling to see that `True` after all this time.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting your runtime is advisable, if it appears as if the other solutions did not work.