# CUDA not available in PyTorch after following all installation steps

Tags: python, pycharm, torch

I am trying to get my BERT transformers model to run on CUDA and have followed all the installation steps here:

https://medium.com/@jjlovesstudying/python-cuda-set-up-on-windows-10-for-gpu-support-78126284b085

However after adding the folders to the PATH variable, I restart my Pycharm and run the following command:

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

which brings `False`. I appreciate this is not reproducible but would anyone have any idea how to debug this problem or fix this? Any extra information needed, I'm happy to provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Torch.cuda.is\_available() keeps switching to False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717751/torch-cuda-is-available-keeps-switching-to-false)

Comment: Medium bad, documentation good - did you follow the steps here?: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ (click the fields to build an install line)

Comment: @ti7 This doesn't walk through CUDA installation on windows. My cudnn is installed and fine but as for CUDA when calling `torch.version.cuda` is None? I've run the installer several times now so I'm really lost.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the modules are loaded at each part?
What do you get for `import torch`

Comment: This loads in fine.