# Pytorch could not recognize cuda

Tags: python, pytorch, ray

I am trying to use pytorch and ray to model neural network but I got this error

```
import torch
torch.__version__
>>> '1.12.1'
torch.cuda.is_available()
>>> False
```

I am working with ubuntu 20.04 and nvidia GTX 1070.
I installed pytorch by

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

'numba -s:'

```
_OS Information__
Platform Name                                 : Linux-5.13.0-30-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
Platform Release                              : 5.13.0-30-generic
OS Name                                       : Linux
OS Version                                    : #33~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 7 14:25:10 UTC 2022
OS Specific Version                           : ?
Libc Version                                  : glibc 2.31

__Python Information__
Python Compiler                               : GCC 7.5.0
Python Implementation                         : CPython
Python Version                                : 3.9.12
Python Locale                                 : en_US.UTF-8

__Numba Toolchain Versions__
Numba Version                                 : 0.56.0
llvmlite Version                              : 0.39.0

__LLVM Information__
LLVM Version                                  : 11.1.0

__CUDA Information__
CUDA Device Initialized                       : True
CUDA Driver Version                           : 11.7
CUDA Runtime Version                          : 10.2
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings Available                : False
CUDA NVIDIA Bindings In Use                   : False
CUDA Detect Output:
Found 1 CUDA devices
id 0    b'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070'                              [SUPPORTED]
                      Compute Capability: 6.1
                           PCI Device ID: 0
                              PCI Bus ID: 1
                                    UUID: GPU-5638f16b-a972-087d-1d71-a9a1645d13b1
                                Watchdog: Enabled
             FP32/FP64 Performance Ratio: 32
Summary:
    1/1 devices are supported

CUDA Libraries Test Output:
Finding nvvm from Conda environment
    named  libnvvm.so.3.3.0
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding cudart from Conda environment
    named  libcudart.so.10.2.89
    trying to open library...   ok
Finding cudadevrt from Conda environment
    named  libcudadevrt.a
Finding libdevice from Conda environment
    trying to open library...   ok
```

Nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0    36W /  N/A |    554MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1237      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1844      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                226MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2007      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               73MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5162      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          154MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10045      G   /usr/bin/anydesk                    7MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10217      G   ...RendererForSitePerProcess       44MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

nvcc --version

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:08:53_PST_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
```

What is the problem? The coda env could work with cuda+keras but pytorch wont find cuda.

Does anyone know if I installed all the packages I need? I tried many solutions posted on the internet but still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/72650265 (i.e. uninstalling the pytorch first). You can also check other answers there

Comment: @Dmitry thanks it worked, actually i create a new python venv outside of conda then use that instruction. Thanks