# All cuda, pytorch, cuda toolkit matches, but `torch.cuda.is_available()` still False

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to run a deep learning model on a cluster with an NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB GPU. Here is the version of my Cuda and PyTorch:

```
>>> print(torch.__version__)
2.0.1+cu117
>>> print(torch.version.cuda)
11.7
```

nvcc --version gives me:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_May__3_18:49:52_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.64
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31294372_0
```

nvidia-smi gives me:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.48.07    Driver Version: 515.48.07    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A100-SXM...  On   | 00000000:07:00.0 Off |                   On |
| N/A   28C    P0    41W / 400W |     45MiB / 40960MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |              Enabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

It seems that all versions are matched from my view, **but `torch.cuda.is_available()` is still False.**

I also try `python -m torch.utils.collect_env`, and get the following:

```
PyTorch version: 2.0.1+cu117
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.7
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.27.7
Libc version: glibc-2.31

Python version: 3.8.18 (default, Sep 11 2023, 13:40:15)  [GCC 11.2.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-5.4.0-121-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.17
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.7.64
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB
Nvidia driver version: 515.48.07
cuDNN version: Probably one of the following:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.4.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.4.0
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True
```

Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55717751/torch-cuda-is-available-keeps-switching-to-false

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your PyTorch version (2.0.1+cu117) and CUDA version (11.7) are indeed compatible. However, there could be a few reasons why torch.cuda.is_available() is returning False.

Here are some suggestions to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of PyTorch. You can upgrade PyTorch using the following command:

> pip install --upgrade torch

2. Ensure that your NVIDIA GPU driver is up to date. You mentioned that the driver version is 515.48.07, but it's always a good idea to check for the latest driver from the NVIDIA website.
3. Verify that the CUDA toolkit is correctly installed. Ensure that the CUDA binaries are in your system's PATH. You might need to add the CUDA path to your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

> export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH

Replace /usr/local/cuda with the actual path to your CUDA installation.

4. Make sure cuDNN is installed and in the correct path. PyTorch relies on cuDNN for GPU acceleration. You can download cuDNN from the NVIDIA website and follow the installation instructions.
5. Ensure that your GPU is visible to the system. Check that the GPU is not in exclusive mode and that there are no issues with system permissions.
6. Double-check the compatibility of your PyTorch version with the CUDA version. Ensure that the PyTorch version you are using was built with the correct CUDA version.